# I am looking for a tool like LibCheck to evaluate different versions of the same SDK

Tags: .net, api, backwards-compatibility

I am working on an SDK.  As I release new versions I would like to produce a report of the differences in the API.  This is not the differences in the code.  Most of the code is not expected to be used directly.  The public classes/methods is what I am interested in.  Furthermore, we have adopted the convention that anything in a namespace that includes Implementation should not be used by a client of the SDK.  So I am looking for the differences in the public interfaces, classes and methods that are not in a namespace that includes Implementation.  I want to know what has been removed, added and modified between two releases.

I found a tool from Microsoft called LibCheck that is in the right ballpark.  I have a couple of issues with LibCheck.  LibCheck does not recognize a method that has been modified.  It reports the method as having been removed and added.  It sometime reports a method as having been removed and added, but the name and parameters are all the same.  I do not know what it is attempting to tell me in these cases.  Finally I do not care for the layout of the reports.  I would like a break down by namespace as well as by assembly and class.

I am aware that the reports are the result of an XSLT transform and I could make them look essentially anyway I want.  Still the other issues coupled with a general lack of support for the tool from Microsoft leave me looking for an alternative.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377855/tool-for-backwards-compatibility-for-c-net-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also http://apichange.codeplex.com that has a diffing option. Call it like this

```
ApiChange -diff -old $net2dir\System.dll -new $net4dir\System.dll
```

and you should get a report.

Comment: Its very close. I will look at it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A tool such as [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is very much suited to this job, and has built in features for diff reporting at an "API" level rather than just textual e.g.:

[Compare Builds and Code Diff](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#BuildComparison)

NDepend has its own code query language CQL which can be used to write highly customized static analysis reports:

[Code Query Language](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL)

Comment: See more explanations about NDepend diff here  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-diff-in-visual-studio