# Tool for backwards compatibility for the C#/.NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, binary-compatibility

I found this tool, http://sab39.netreach.com/Software/Japitools/JDK-Results/46/, which checks for backwards compatibility between different versions of APIs for Java using javadoc.

Is there an tool equivalent to this one for C#/.NET?

Here is an example of a comparison between JDK 1.5 and JDK 6 APIs using this tool:
http://www.kaffe.org/~stuart/japi/htmlout/h-jdk15-jdk6

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [ApiChange](http://apichange.codeplex.com/) does take a set of "old" assemblies and a set of "new" assemblies which are diffed for potentially breaking Api changes:

  > ApiChange -diff -old HelloWorldV1.dll -new HelloWorldV2.dll
- [LibCheck](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4b5b7f29-1939-4e5b-a780-70e887964165&displaylang=en) allows you to compare two versions of an assembly and determine the differences. The tool reports the differences as a combination of "removed" and "added" APIs:

  > LibCheck -store HelloWorld.dll 1.0 -full C:\HelloWorldV1\
  >   LibCheck -store HelloWorld.dll 2.0 -full C:\HelloWorldV2\
  >   LibCheck -compare 1.0 2.0

See also ["Working with LibCheck"](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/BrainDump/Working-with-LibCheck/), ["Highlight Public API Differences Between Assembly Revisions"](http://mattonsoftware.com/archive/2006/09/28/21.aspx) and ["Api Diff Between Assemblies"](http://apichange.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diff&referringTitle=Documentation) articles.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't tried the Java tool you linked to, but [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#BuildComparison) has some powerful tools for comparing two sets of binaries and highlighting any differences.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this library
https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/dotnet-compatibility
seems to provide what you'd want.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tunnelvisionlabs/dotnet-compatibility/master/CompatibilityCheckExample/Program.cs

```
IPackageRepository sourceRepository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/");
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(sourceRepository, temporaryDirectory);
packageManager.PackageInstalled += HandlePackageInstalled;
packageManager.InstallPackage("Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable", SemanticVersion.Parse("1.0.34"));
packageManager.InstallPackage("System.Collections.Immutable", SemanticVersion.Parse("1.1.33-beta"));

using (PEReader referenceAssembly = new PEReader(File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(temporaryDirectory, "Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable.1.0.34", "lib", "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81", "System.Collections.Immutable.dll"))))
{
    using (PEReader newAssembly = new PEReader(File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(temporaryDirectory, "System.Collections.Immutable.1.1.33-beta", "lib", "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81", "System.Collections.Immutable.dll"))))
    {
        Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(referenceAssembly, newAssembly, null);
        analyzer.Run();
    }
}
```